# Naturality of Transformations

Tags: category-theory

When we say some arrow $\eta _A$ is natural in $A$ ($A$ being an object of the category in question, $\mathsf C$), we mean it is a component of a natural transformation. I have consistently stumbled upon statements in the spirit of:

> The natuality of $\eta _A$ in $A$ means that the object $A$ is dispensable and is merely a representative of objects in $\mathsf C$.

I'm trying to understand *exactly* how this follows from the definition. The nicest formulation for the definition I have come up with is the following:

> For each arrow class $\mathsf {Hom}_{\mathsf C}(A,B)$ there are two arrows $\eta _A:FA\rightarrow GA$ and $\eta _B:FB\rightarrow GB$ that make the usual square commute independently of which arrow we take in $\mathsf {Hom}_{\mathsf C}(A,B)$.

The only systematic aspect I see here is the independence of $\eta _A$ and $\eta _B$ of the arrow $f\in \mathsf {Hom}_{\mathsf C}(A,B)$ whose images we take by $F$ and $G$ to make the commutative square. I do not, however, see how this definition ignores particular properties of the objects $A,B$.

So where does this notion of naturality hide in the definition of natural transformations?

---

***Big Addition:***
As my initial question was probably too vague, I'm adding a excerpt from Marquis's *From a Geometrical Point of View - A Study of the History and Philosophy of Category Theory*. I do not understand how some portions (underlined in blue) follow from the formal definitions, even heuristically. I would ***very much*** like explanations because according to the underlined bits, naturality is *exactly* what we'd like it to be.

[image]

Comment: From what you write, it looks like $\mathsf{C}$ is the domain category. So to say "$A$ is merely a representative of objects in $\mathsf{C}$" is silly, because $A$ just is an object of $\mathsf{C}$. If you gave more context, we could maybe help you ungarble this statement.

Comment: @tcamps, I added plenty of context :)

Comment: It seems to me that this is just a verbose way of saying "dummy variable".

Comment: @ZhenLin, but how does the definition of natural transformations capture the fact the object $A$ in each component $\tau _A$ is a dummy variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The words "dispensible" and "merely a representative" are just informal descriptions of the definition of a natural transformation. Therefore you won't be able to find a "proof" from the definition. The definition says what it says and it cannot really be simplified. Another informal description is that the $\eta_A$ vary "continuously with $A$". This is similar to the notion of a homotopy (cf. [MO/64365](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64365/natural-transformations-as-categorical-homotopies)).

Comment: I understand there's no formal proof for what I said. I want to understand why and how this definition, as it is, encodes the idea that $A$ is "merely a representative".

Comment: one could also say that the isomorphism is "uniform in $A$". @Exterior: isn't this obivous?

Comment: @313, Perhaps.. Unfortunately, not to me..

Comment: @Exterior: have you seen a use of the commutative diagram that one gets by definition of a natural transformation?

Comment: @313 The naturality squares? Certainly.

Comment: @Martin, I have added alot of context to my question. Perhaps you could shed some light?